# How configure the confirmation minibuffer to use Enter, instead y?

Tags: minibuffer

When you want to do something, you get sometimes a confirmation prompt in the minibuffer, with pressing yes or no to proceed.

I'm aware that you could change this with typing <kbd>y</kbd> instead `yes` with the following setting.

```
(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)  ;; Ask for y/n instead of yes/no
```

I'm wondering if you could configure this in a way that he will accept <kbd>RET</kbd> as `y`?

Comment: Yes; redefine `y-or-n-p` to treat `RET` the same as `y`. (Personally, I find that if Emacs uses `yes-or-no-p` it usually has a good reason for it.)

Comment: Drew, in the source code of y-or-n-p, there is a conditional that reads the input from the string: `((member str '("y" "Y")) (setq answer 'act))` So I need to read the key instead a string. I have looked into the Emacs documentation how to receive key inputs from <RET>, without result. Any suggestion?

Comment: The way the function is written, a blank string `""` equals `RET` -- i.e., `read-string`.  Evaluate:  `(read-string "Hello-World:  ")` and then press the return key and watch the echo area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @phils commented simply redefining the key in `query-replace-map` will effect other things as well. The following copies the key-map to avoid that:

```el
(defun y-or-n-p-with-return (orig-func &rest args)
  (let ((query-replace-map (copy-keymap query-replace-map)))
    (define-key query-replace-map (kbd "RET") 'act)
    (apply orig-func args)))        

(advice-add 'y-or-n-p :around #'y-or-n-p-with-return)
```

Comment: It didn't worked out. When I mark multiple files in Dired, and delete it. I need to confirm with `yes-or-no` to delete the files. When I press `RET`, then it will not work. When I press `y`, it will work. So it seems me that there is an error in your solution?

Comment: @ReneFroger Hm, don't know whats wrong. Does it work when you just eval `(y-or-n-p "test")`?. I don't use dired, maybe this is not the function which get's called?

Comment: Are you sure it works properly on your side?

Comment: @ReneFroger Yes, it works. I tried it with emacs -Q and it works as well.

Comment: You're right, it turned out that I disabled the `(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)` setting. Now fixed and your snipping works like a charm.